# Why don't my scene expand to full size?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm having a problem where my scene won't expand the the full size so an image on the bottom pane is only half view able.

The scene is setup with a menubar, splitepane, then a bottompane. The scene seems to adjust accordingly with width but cuts in half of the bottompane.
e.g

[Image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWK1q.png)

Code for panes and scene..

```
 VBox root = new VBox();
 Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1300, 900);

 root.getChildren().add(menuBar); 

 SplitPane splitPane = new SplitPane();
 splitPane.setPrefSize(1300,900);
 root.getChildren().add(splitPane); 


 HBox bottomPane = new HBox();
 HBox bottomPane = new HBox();
 root.getChildren().add(bottomPane);

 stage.setMaximized(true);
 stage.setMinWidth(500);
 stage.setMinHeight(550);
 stage.setScene(scene);
 stage.show();
```

**I think i'm just going to maximize the scene when it is run**

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make us able to help.

Comment: Try to change the root to a `BorderPane`, then `root.setTop(menuBar); root.setCenter(splitPane ); root.setBottom(bottomPane);`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sizeToScene? I hope that is what you are looking for. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/sizeToScene.htm

Comment: You will have to remove the hard coded width and height of the respective node before applying sizeToScene